# data-bind interference with custom tooltip CSS style

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, razor, knockout.js

I am trying to create a tool tip popup that will appear when I mouse over an element on screen. I am using Type script with knockout for my java script code and cshtml. so far what I have concluded is that the **data-bind="text: Value"** is interfering with the **class="tooltipcustom"**.

here is a working version of the style below on W3schools. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip)
If I put a static Value into the tooltipcustom span it works perfectly but does not when I make it a data bound value.

I have research extensively and have only found one answer that seemed like it may work. they suggested to add a custom binding for tool tip but I am unable to do that in the current situation of the project.

```
<style>
.tooltipcustom {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

    .tooltipcustom .tooltiptext {
        visibility: hidden;
        width: 120px;
        background-color: #555;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 6px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        bottom: 125%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -60px;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 0.3s;
    }

    .tooltipcustom .tooltiptext::after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 5px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
    }

    .tooltipcustom:hover .tooltiptext {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
```

This Div loops through a list of codes and each code has a list of the fields. each field will have its own tool tip that you can hover over that will give you the information about that field. the output would look like so with each separate data field having its own tool tip.

35B A 0000000000 00 001 02 BI  250-500 0000210  0000000
35B A 0000000000 00 001 03 PD  50  0000310  0000000
35B A 0000000000 00 001 04 UMB 250-500 0000008  0000000

```
<div data-bind="foreach: segmentCodes">
        <div data-bind="foreach: fields">
            <span class="tooltipcustom" data-bind="text: Value">
                <span class="tooltiptext">test</span>
            </span>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick here is to use container less binding

`<!-- ko text: value --><!-- /ko -->`

to stop overwriting the inner html

```js
var ViewModel = {
  segmentCodes: [{
      fields: [{
        value: 'some value',
        tooltip: 'some value tooltip'
      }, {
        value: 'some value 22',
        tooltip: 'some value 22 tooltip'
      }]
    },
    {
      fields: [{
        value: 'other value',
        tooltip: 'other value tooltip'
      }]
    }
  ]
};

ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
```

```css
.tooltipcustom {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltipcustom .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltipcustom .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltipcustom:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.main {
  margin: 50px;
}

.main span {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="main" data-bind="foreach: segmentCodes">
  <div data-bind="foreach: fields">
    <span class="tooltipcustom">
      <!-- ko text: value --><!-- /ko -->
      <span class="tooltiptext" data-bind="text: tooltip"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```